# slCreateEngine while another engine ******* is active

Tags: android

My application give up working correctly. An activity that uses and external library stops his life and it give me this logcat message

```
 libOpenSLES    slCreateEngine while another engine ******* is active..
```

I don't use any function that require this library. Till yeterday this app work. And anhother app that use the same external library work. 
I'm going crazy.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSL library is used for playing audio. Before starting a player, an instance of Engine is created. There must be a single instance of engine created. If second instance is created, then you will see the message in the log.

I believe you call a method creates that Engine multiple times. This usually happens in Activity lifecycle methods like `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, etc. Double check those methods.

- If you call a method like *create* or *init* of your library in `onCreate()`, `onStart()` or in `onResume()`, make sure you call corresponding *destroy* or *release* methods in symmetrical `onDestroy()`, `onStop()` or `onResume()` methods of your activity.
- If there are no *destroy* or *release* methods in your library, make sure you do not call *create* or *init* methods in `onStart()` or `onResume()`.

Hope this helps to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I override only the on create and i never call any method or costructor ofOpenSL